# AR-iPhone -> cocos2D?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am currently planning a little sightseeing-app (game) for my iPhone. It should be something like geocaching with Augmented-Reality features. The user should search and then pick up virtual elements. These elements should be "stored".

Would you recommend using cocos2D for this? I am a programmer with no iPhone programming experience ;-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on some of the deeper technical requirements of your game.  Cocos2D is great, I have been using it for several months now and have little to complain about with it.

You mention "augmented-reality" features which to me says using the camera while overlaying annotations on top of the camera display.  Is that right?  I could see Cocos2D being used as a transparent overlay over the camera display where you markup various parts of the display.  It would be a bit of a challenge no doubt to make sure your annotations match up with what is shown in the camera but I think it could be done.

Best to do a quick tech demo and see if that meets your needs.